# How to handle redirect response from server in Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

ember-data 1.0, ember 1.5.1, rails 3.2

How to handle redirect response from server? In ember-data 0.13 I do:

```
Staas.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  didCreateRecord: (store, type, record, payload) ->
    if payload.redirect
      window.location.replace payload.redirect
      return

    @_super(store, type, record, payload)
```

But now there are no didCreateRecord method in Adapter. I want to implement universal solution, not in each save promises.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reopen the RESTAdapter and modify the ajax method method for all instances.

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
      var adapter = this;

      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        hash = adapter.ajaxOptions(url, type, hash);

        hash.success = function( json ) {
          Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
        };

        hash.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          Ember.run(null, reject, adapter.ajaxError(jqXHR));
        };

        Ember.$.ajax(hash);
      }, "DS: RestAdapter#ajax " + type + " to " + url).then(function(json){
        if(json && json.redirect){
          //redirect here
          alert('redirect');
        }
        return json;
      }, function(jqXHR){
        if(jqXHR.status == 302){  
          //redirect here
          alert('redirect');
        }
        return jqXHR;
      });
    },

  });
```

Example 302 status: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/796/edit

Example payload: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/798/edit